# Huge difference for !heap -l results in Windbg between debug and release build

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-leaks, windbg

I am trying to duplicate a potential memory leak issue with one of our applications. I started a debug version and a release version of the application and used Windbg to see if I can find any potential memory leak. The command I used is !heap -l. For the debug build,

```
68 potential unreachable blocks were detected.
```

and for release build

```
94494 potential unreachable blocks were detected.
```

Can anyone tell me why there is such a huge difference between the results of the debug and release build?

Comment: Your name hints to what's the reason: optmization. In release build, the compiler usually works under high optimization levels (-O2, or maybe even -O3) scanning through the code for unused assignments (removing variables and functions calls), calculating values "in place" if they could be evaluated at compile time, etc. Consider this: some constant expression used in an `if` renders half of your code base never to be used. Release build will optimize that half away.

Comment: @hauron Then how can I tell which detected memory leaks are true leaks and which are just false due to compiler optimization.

Comment: The debug CRT uses a completely different heap structure, algorithms etc see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx